# Choose from disks in Python?

Tags: python, unix

I'm writing a `Python` program that uses `dd` to write an OS image to a USB flash drive. Drives `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb` are mounted, in my case, with `sdb` being the flash drive I want to write to.

However, on someone else's system, the drive they want to write to might be `/dev/sdc`. How do I let the user choose what drive to write to? Preferably letting them choose by disk label, for user friendliness.

EDIT: Let me rephrase this: I've got the USB flash drives /dev/sdb and /dev/sdc inserted. I want to basically tell the user; "Which flash drive do you want to write to, sdb or sdc?", then write to the disk that the user chose. So far, I've found no way to do this.

Comment: please, add some snippet showing what you've already got

Comment: @Rubens Were some of those edits really necessary? Putting code tags around Python, OS image and USB flash drive?

Comment: They were not the only things I've edited there, although I found a bit more comfortable adding those highlightings...

Comment: I realize that, which is why I said "some of those edits", not "those edits".

Comment: Well, if you find them unnecessary, simply remove them, and wait for an accept on your edit, so the changes are shown.

Answer (score 1):

What you want here is definitely `psutil`.

https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil

```
>>> psutil.disk_partitions()
[partition(device='/dev/sda1', mountpoint='/', fstype='ext4'), 
partition(device='/dev/sdb5', mountpoint='/media/Storage', fstype='ext4')]
```

This gives you information about all mounted disks. Best of all, it's cross platform.

Answer (score 0):

If your program is *nix-specific, I suppose your best bet is parsing the output of `mount` command.

It gives you mount points, user names, and FS names. Of them you could filter points mounted or at least writable by the current user, with a right FS on it (possibly vfat?).